# How to pass/use Camel Exchange Headers to camel-jolt component

Tags: apache-camel

I've written some jolt transformations using camel-jolt and am at a point where I need a way to access exchange headers from my camel route for substitution in my json payload. How can I achieve this? I tried using in.header. and header. but they didn't work. Could someone experienced with camel-jolt please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not supported in camel-jolt. You are welcome to dive into the source code and see if you can implement support for this. The Apache Camel project loves contributions: http://camel.apache.org/contributing